# RestAssured Outh login isuue to Twitter

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to collect most recent tweets from Twitter account, I Learning Rest Assured. I try to authenticate and get latest Tweets.
below is my code.

```
public void login() {

    Acess_Token="8043781991*************";

    Acess_secret="inPu8Lj8w0Bmn4Oev*******";      

    con_key = "6zGwLKv6exZvfdN*******";

    con_secret ="bjqtTinlDusTGgo0WTjMdaYldhb0AVetnwe******";

    Response res = given().authentication().oauth(con_key, con_secret, Acess_Token, Acess_secret)
                    .param("screen_name", "balaji koc")
                    .when()
                    .get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json");

    // System.out.println(res.asString());
}
```

my script is not executing showing error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:"

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

It should be given().auth() (instead of authentication).

Also, if using OAuth 1, according to the wiki, you need to get Scribe too.

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/usage#oauth-1

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
Response res = given().authentication().oauth(con_key, con_secret, Acess_Token, Acess_secret)
```

TO

```
 Response res=  given().auth().oauth(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Token, TokenSecret)
```

And add following jars

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

above jar is depend on this jar

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.scribejava/scribejava-core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
                <artifactId>scribejava-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

add two jars it will work

Comment: Hey @monil I know this is old but this not work in my case I add the two dependencies to maven and I have the newest RestAssured and I still got Unauthorized error from Twitter for oauth1 authentication.Where could be the problem